# Heroku error H10 status 503 Python flask app

Tags: python, flask, heroku

trying to upload and make work my first flask app online. I choose heroku but I am getting this error (error H10 status 503) over and over again. I tried everything I find online, but I am lost now.

I find few posts here with the same porblem, but they were not answered or the sollution doesnt help me.

[https://github.com/Happydeath97/googleit](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) here is my github repository I'm trying  to upload.

my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn main:app
```

my requirements.txt:

```
beautifulsoup4==4.11.2
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==3.0.1
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
Flask==2.2.3
idna==3.4
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
requests==2.28.2
soupsieve==2.4
urllib3==1.26.14
Werkzeug==2.2.3
```

my main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from scrap_google import get_links


app = Flask(__name__)
port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/search_with_google', methods=['post'])
def get_searching_term():
    search_term = request.form['search_term']

    links = get_links(search_term)
    return render_template('index.html', links=links)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

i tryied:

- changing the Procfile several times
- in main delete the app.run() line or add it back and specify port
- check requirements
- make new venv and generate new requirements

But in the end i always get: `Application error An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served.`

and in Heroku CLI:

```
2023-03-03T10:03:52.685876+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=googleit.herokuapp.com request_id=e3904949-d7ec-453d-818b-ec2f4539826d fwd="188.154.14.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-03-03T10:03:52.753500+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=googleit.herokuapp.com request_id=21ef483f-bd9c-481a-8d7c-8f247706702c fwd="188.154.14.75" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing `import OS` in main.py and in requirements.txt missing gunicorn. I am sorry to waste your time ppl :D I am just blind